# FLUTTER/DARTTrying to convert a List<T> to JsonString to save in sharedPreferences. <T> has a Contact object and bool value

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Trying to save a list in shared sharedpreferences by converting to JsonString. But repeatedly getting the encodable object failed : Instance of 'CustonContact'. Help out

```
    class CustomContact extends Contact{
      Contact contact;
      bool isChecked;
    
      CustomContact({
        this.contact,
        this.isChecked = false,
      });
      
      Map toJson() {
        return {
          'contact': contact,
          'isChecked': isChecked,
        };
      }
    
      CustomContact.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
          : contact = json['contact'],
            isChecked = json['isChecked'];
    }
    
    ****Trying to call it in here to save in sharedpreference****
    
      _saveTrustedContactsNames() async {
        SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        List<CustomContact> _contactsSelectedNames = [];
        for (var _customContact in contactsSelected) {     **contactsSelected is already populated** 
          setState(() {
            _contactsSelectedNames.add(_customContact);
          });
        }
    **trying to convert to JsonString**
        String _trustedContactsJson = jsonEncode(_contactsSelectedNames); 
        print(_trustedContactsJson);
        preferences.setString('_contactstrusted', _trustedContactsJson);
      }
```

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it has answered your query. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

That's cause sharedPreferences can't automatically convert `Contact` to json. You'll need to create a `toJson` method in `Contact` and pass that method in to your `CustomContact`'s `toJson` method and vice versa for the `fromJson`.

```
Map toJson() {
  return {
    'contact': contact.toJson(),
    'isChecked': isChecked,
  };
}
CustomContact.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
    : contact = Contact.fromJson(json['contact']),
      isChecked = json['isChecked'];
```